# How to enable real-time scrolling in Citrix Receiver?

Tags: microsoft-word, citrix-receiver

I need to use Microsoft Word through [Citrix Receiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrix_Receiver). As far as I can tell, Citrix Receiver uses some kind of VNC connection to display software that is running on a remote computer.

The frustrating thing for me is that, when I grab a scrollbar with the mouse and drag it, the window content does not move until I release the mouse button.

I assume this is being done by MS Word or the windowing toolkit upon realizing that it is running over a remote display, to reduce bandwidth. However I would like to disable this feature. Is it possible?